# Extract multiple rows with same id mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hi I have the following table:

```
id  request_id  ein intervention_date   time_slot
10  1   600545383   18/05/2015 00:00    AM
11  3   802877145   01/06/2015 00:00    AM
12  3   802310154   02/06/2015 00:00    PM
13  3   801777170   03/06/2015 00:00    AM
```

I have the following query:

```
function get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id){
        $connection = get_db();
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM coach_request_assignment WHERE request_id='.$request_id;
        return $connection->query($query);
    }
```

When I call this function, it returns only the first row where `request_id=3`how to extract all the values returned by the query?

This is what I have tried:

```
$coach_request_assignment_data = get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id);
$coach_request_assignment_data = $coach_request_assignment_data->fetch_assoc();
```

That's how the `var_dump($coach_request_assignment_data)` looks like:

```
array (size=5)
  'id' => string '11' (length=2)
  'request_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'coach_uin' => string '802877145' (length=9)
  'date_intervention' => string '2015-06-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
  'time_slot' => string 'AM' (length=2)
```

Thanks here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the mysqli extension?

What about trying:

```
$coach_request_assignment_data->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This will fetch the entire result set at once, rather than needing to loop through it yourself. The MYSQLI_ASSOC tells it to return it in an associative array with the column names included. The default is MYSQLI_NUM, which simply returns a numerical-indexed array with no column names.

Comment: However, this erases the column names and replace them with `string`

Comment: Glad I could help! I'll edit my answer to include the MYSQLI_ASSOC

Answer (score 3):

If this is a `MySQLi` API, then you'll need multiple invocations of `fetch_assoc()` in order to get those multiple rows. You have only invoked `->fetch_assoc()` once:

```
$results = get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id);
$coach_data = array();
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $coach_data[] = $row; // push row
}
// print_r($coach_data);
```

Comment: I Tried this: `$coach_request_assignment_data = get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id);
while($row = $coach_request_assignment_data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $coach_data['coach_uin'] =  $row['coach_uin'];
}` but this returns only the first records `uin`...

Comment: @Shery yes, do note that you'll overwrite `$coach_data['coach_uin']` each iteration

Comment: I changed it but still no luck: `$coach_request_assignment_data = get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id);
while($row = $coach_request_assignment_data->fetch_assoc()) {
    $i = 1;
    $coach_data[$i]['coach_uin'] =  $row['coach_uin'];
    $i++;
}` result is still the same: `array (size=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'coach_uin' => string '801777170' (length=9)`

Comment: @Shery your `$i` should be outside the loop intialize outside, anyway i made the edit in my answer, if you'd like to store it inside a container

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PDO::query() ? If yes, query() returns a PDOStatement which you can loop over, e.g :

```
$results = get_coach_request_assignment_on_request_id($request_id);
foreach ($results as $result) {
   //do something with $result
}
```

Doc : http://php.net/manual/fr/pdo.query.php